# Call typed.js function inside Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I using [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) library for text animation on my home component.
I can't figure out how to call a typed function inside my home template.

```
export default {
 name: 'home',
 mounted: function () {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  Typed.new('.element', {
      strings: ['Lorem ipsum'],
      typeSpeed: 10
     });
   });
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: `import Typed from 'path/to/typed.js'`

Comment: Incidentally you don't want to be adding DOM event watchers here; let Vue manage its own lifecycle.  (If you're in `mounted()` that means the component's DOM node already exists.)

Comment: @DanielBeck I tried to import, I got this msg in console: Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__static_js_typed_min_js___default.a.new is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:748), <anonymous>:22:74)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've been working with npm modules too exclusively, forgot that not every library is `import`able...

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help! I found some type component on github so I will try with this one https://cngu.github.io/vue-typer/

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
Install typed js from npm, by typing the command

```
npm install typed.js --save
```

In main.js file

```
import Typed from 'typed.js'
```

Step 2:
To fix Typed method global to all the components

```
global.Typed = Typed;
```

So the result looks like this,

main.js:

```
import Typed from 'typed.js'
global.Typed = Typed
```

It works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by removing the event listener, since mounted only runs once the element is loaded anyway, and by passing a template to the component.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <p class="element">test</p>
  `,
  mounted() {
    Typed.new('.element', {
      strings: ['Lorem ipsum'],
      typeSpeed: 10
    });
  }
})
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/2016/

Comment: Thanks Mauro, that's looks great! But I have one problem about importing Typed.js in the component. I using vue-webpack template, so if I include typed.js in my index.html, I got error like typed is not defined. I am trying to import typed.js in template.

Comment: I understand the issue you're having. It seems like there's an open ticket about this on typed.js github. Check it out, it might have a workaround. https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/issues/121

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
yarn add typed.js
```

then add these lines to the file where you'll set up the Vue component:

```
import Typed from 'typed.js';

if(document.getElementById('typed-element') !== null) {
const typed = new Vue({
  el: '#typed-element',
  mounted() {
    var options = {
      strings: ["<i>First</i> sentence.", "&amp; a second sentence."],
      typeSpeed: 40
    }
    new Typed('#typed-element', options)
  }
})
```

}

And you should be set

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the `typed.js` package was installed with `yarn` or `npm`. Make sure to install it directly from GitHub, since the `npm` package is outdated.

```
npm install https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js.git --save

OR

yarn add https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js.git
```

Now you can import the `typed.js` package like this:

`import Typed from 'typed.js'`

Finally, you can create your `typed` instance:

```
const options = {
  strings: ["<i>First</i> sentence.", "&amp; a second sentence."],
  typeSpeed: 40
}
new Typed('#typed-element', options)
```

Or you can simply use my `vue-typed-js` plugin: https://github.com/Orlandster1998/vue-typed-js